# js in HTML any way to release function?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

my webapp using lots of ajax. So ajax also loads necessary js for current module and while switching between modules using `$(script).remove();` js functions remain in memory so when I load this module again I getting duplicated functions, is there way to load functions by ajax and release them w/o page reload?

Comment: How big are the functions that their mere existence on the page is using so much memory that you want to try to get it back?  I say only load the functions that you need, and don't load any that you already have loaded (do a check or whatever before loading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe instead of release functions you will use requirejs, which will only load modules (with functions of course) when they are needed.

In this solution you will avoid double loading same functions.